# Git workflow - updating remote images

Tags: git, phing

I'm trying to work out the git command set to accommodate the following routine:

1) I run phing following the CI build to create separate images 
     for github and the production web server.

That leaves me with two directories each containing source files
  that comprise the latest release for each destination.

2) I want to update the local bare repo on the development server with branches for
     each image.

3) I want to then update each upstream repo master branch with the just created
     local branch from the local bare repo without any fast-forward issues - just
     a hard push and replacement.  The web server has a post-receive hook ready to
     publish the push.

I'm not a complete git novice and I've experimented with a few different strategies,
  but I'd really like get some feedback on possible solutions.

Thanks, -km

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're looking for the [`git push -f`](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-push.html) command, which allows you to push a *specific* reference to a remote without regard for what the remote had previously. Note that the repository you're pushing into must have the `receive.denyNonFastforwards` option set to `false` (the default is `true` to prevent you from accidentally losing history).

Comment: That's useful info, thanks.  I'm still wondering if I'll have to do a git init/add/commit in each dir where these files are being dropped in order to then ship the branches to the local repo or is there a way to point the local repo at these files and have them stored as a branch.

Comment: @YMOZ Sure! The usual should work: `git checkout -b <branch name> <commit>`.